# Prepared statement error in PHP

Tags: php, sql, prepared-statement

I have the following SQL query that is executed using PHP, $q is a variable with a string in it.

```
$sql =$conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM namebase WHERE name LIKE "%?%"');
$sql->bind_param('s', $q);
$sql->execute();
```

While executing, I receive an error message saying,

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in C:\xampp\htdocs\file\s.php on line 39
```

Line 39 is `$sql->bind_param('s', $q);`

What is causing this error? I am only passing one variable to the query. Then why is it showing this error message?

Comment: is `$q` an array maybe?

Comment: @Jeff, change bind_param to bind value and check it again

Comment: @Jeff Its just a string.

Comment: The wildcard symbols (like `%`) should be part of the value and not part of the query. Also, quotes are part of the value too. You should probably watch [this quick video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the comments on the documentation page for the `mysqli_stmt::bind_param` method, someone has come across exactly the same problem: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#102048

> I had a problem with the LIKE operator
>
> This code did not work:
>
> ```
> <?php
> $test = $sql->prepare("SELECT name FROM names WHERE name LIKE %?%");
> $test->bind_param("s", $myname);
> ?>
> ```
>
> The solution is:
>
> ```
> <?php
> $test = $sql->prepare("SELECT name FROM names WHERE name LIKE ?");
> $param = "%" . $myname . "%";
> $test->bind_param("s", $param);
> ?>
> ```

Comment: You really should avoid using the closing `?>` tag

Answer (score -1):

If you have access to the database I would suggest creating a Stored Procedure.

And then create as follows:

```
getNames(
    IN nameVAR VARCHAR(256)
)

SELECT * FROM namebase WHERE name LIKE ‘%nameVAR%’;
```

Then in your php call getName(?) instead of putting your current statement

Comment: You would specifically set how many variables the procedure is expecting

Comment: Why would you want to create a stored procedure for a simple `SELECT` query? This is really over complicating a simple problem.

Comment: It’s also good practise to use stored procedures and adds the most security to you database calls

Comment: I would argue that creating stored procedures for every query would be a bad practice. A database can serve data to many applications at the same time. These applications might start with the same requirements and drift apart as time passes. Either you change the procedures to fit one app (and might mess up others), or your database will be infested with new procedures each time an app's requirements changes. That will be a proper mess. Just let the app fetch the data they need in the way they need it directly.

Comment: I suppose it’s situational and preference, but it can help to maintain you code easier knowing that any sql will be located all in the same place and not mixed in your php

Comment: But it's the application that decides what data in wants and how it wants it. The database should be totally agnostic about which data the applications need and how they use it. The database should only care about it's own data integrity. Yes, sometimes you need a stored procedure, but that's when the database needs to do some magic for it's one sake, not for the sake of the calling application. I've worked with systems that have used a lot of stored procedure for business logic. It's usually a mess and ends up with many similar procedures (for BC).

Comment: It’s also nice just to put code reusability into practise as I see to many people typing out statements over and over

Comment: Code reusability is the apps responsibility, not the databases. Code = app. Data = database.